# MS-SQL permissions on stored Proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-science, database-administration

Can Stored Proc be given "Execute" Privileges without giving table privileges. Meaning just giving a user permission to execute stored Calls and nothing else.

This was my interview question today. And I said "Yes" but the person interviewing said I was wrong. I just want to be sure so I can email back with the correct Answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes it can. Take a look at https://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html for  a comprehensive description.

Comment: @Dale K! FIXED. Yes that was a auto correct error :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do that. you have to simply give EXECUTE permission on the stored procedure to the user.

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE ON schemaName.StoredProcedureName TO UserName
```

Comment: Will it work by just giving the access to Execute the PROCEDURE and without having the access to tables?

Comment: That is my question. Will stored Call will return Error! Please someone test this in a MS SQL environment. Thanks!

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty, yes. It will work. I have tested it earlier. For unprivileged user, if you give execute permission on stored procedure, it will allow him to operate on tables, to which he is not having access to.